# 自作のAndroidアプリを長時間起動したままにすることは可能ですか？

Tags: android

作成するandroidアプリケーションを長時間(10時間程)、毎日稼働したいと思っています。

長時間アプリケーションを動かすことは可能ですか？
可能だとして注意点などはありますか？

Comment: いわゆるフォアグラウンドアプリなのかバックグラウンドサービスなのか、どっちでしょ？

Comment: こちらでも返信ありがとうございます。両方での意見お願いします！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

バックグラウンドサービスってことだと例えば IP 電話ソフトなんかは典型的待ち受け daemon です。なので電源投入直後に起動し、２４時間ずっと待機しているなんてのは普通にできます。
（が、予期せぬタイミングで強制終了させられいるとかありがち）

フォアグラウンドアプリを起動し続けるってのは想像がつかないんですが bitcoin の miner でも作るんですか？　（ビットコインマイナーは Google が禁止しちゃいましたけど）

フォアグラウンドアプリを起動しても、ユーザーがタッチ・タップせず放置プレイしているとスマホ自体が省電力モードに入るのでソフトは停止するでしょうし、

動かせ続けることができたとしても、
　= スマホ本体過熱で停止させられるかもしれない
　= スマホの電池消耗につき停止させられるかもしれない
　= 充電しながら使い続けると電池の寿命（＝製品寿命）が短くなりそう

あたりが挙げられそうです。

# 出来の良いゲームにユーザーがハマって一日中プレイしてるとかだと
 # 断続的に１０時間使われた
 # なんてことになったら開発者としては誇っていい。